# How to set one card to the left and bottom to second card in different screens

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm in my beginning of Web development, and I built a simple HTML web page with bootstrap-4.

I want to display 2 card horizontally so the image card will be in the left to the text card. When the screen is small I want the image to be below the text card. But if the card in the left to the second card it automatically display above it.

My code is like that:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="card mb-3">
      <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/10/Cranes_made_by_Origami_paper.jpg/220px-Cranes_made_by_Origami_paper.jpg" class="card-img-bottom" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p>The text card in the right to the image card.</p>
            <p>In small page the text card below to the image card.<br>But I want to display it above the image card.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <title>Que</title>

  <style type="text/css">

  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="card mb-3">
      <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/10/Cranes_made_by_Origami_paper.jpg/220px-Cranes_made_by_Origami_paper.jpg" class="card-img-bottom" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p>The text card in the right to the image card.</p>
            <p>In small page the text card below to the image card.<br>But I want to display it above the image card.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The horizontal result is:

[image]

And the vertical result for small screen is:

[image]

I want to display the image in the bottom, below to the text card in small screens, but in the left in wide screens.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set order class **order-1 ,order-2 and order-md-1, order-md-2** for changing position for desktop and mobile

> Since Bootstrap 4 is flexbox, it's easy to change the [order of
>   columns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#order-classes). The cols can be ordered from order-1 to order-12,
>   responsively such as order-md-12 order-2 (last on md, 2nd on xs)
>   relative to the parent .row, The responsive ordering classes are 
>   order-first, order-last and order-0 - order-12.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <title>Que</title>

  <style type="text/css">

  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="card mb-3">
      <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-md-5 order-md-1 order-2">
          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/10/Cranes_made_by_Origami_paper.jpg/220px-Cranes_made_by_Origami_paper.jpg" class="card-img-bottom" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7 order-md-2 order-1">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p>The text card in the right to the image card.</p>
            <p>In small page the text card below to the image card.<br>But I want to display it above the image card.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you please give me a short explain?

Comment: @nirKa yes sure